# passing variable to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongojs

**In case anyone else reads this, I've answered my own stupid question.
The problem was that I was storing the value as an integer, but searching for it as a string.
Pro tip: Store stuff as string values or;
When querying for a integer, while using a variable, use parseInt(variable).
It'll save you hours of pondering.**

I'm simply trying to pass a variable along to mongodb (using mongojs), but it seems that it doesn't work if it's not a string or something.

I need to use the `$gte` and `$lte` to find some documents. The variable comes from `app.get()` `/get/prods?startdate=1431057999826&enddate=1433563599832`

The document look like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5571288438e80a073c0fc32c"), 
    "account" : "AC654164545-006",
    "uip" : 1217390010, 
    "ci" : "products", 
    "ts" : 1433479300668, 
    "guid" : "_upzghlayx", 
    "title" : "test_prod", 
    "type" : "car" 
}
```

This works just fine:

```
db.data.find({"account":'AC654164545-006', "ts": {$gte: 1431057999826, $lte: 1433563599832}});
```

But when I grab the query string, like so (the variables are the proper numbers, so I know they are correct):

```
var datestart = req.query.startdate;
var dateend = req.query.enddate;
```

and query using them:

```
db.data.find({"account":'AC654164545-006', "ts": {$gte: datestart, $lte: dateend}})
```

I get 0 results. I've also tried building the query beforehand.

```
var search = { "account":'AC654164545-006'};

search['ts'] = {$gte: datestart, $lte: dateend};
```

Again, 0 results. However if I switch to manual input without the variables, it works fine again.

```
search['ts'] = {$gte: 1431057999826, $lte: 1433563599832};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O.M.G.........

So, After reading my own question, and thinking about it, I realized that the document value "ts" is being stored as an integer.

So I changed:

```
search['ts'] = {$gte: datestart, $lte: dateend};
```

to

```
search['ts'] = {$gte: parseInt(datestart), $lte: parseInt(dateend)};
```

Ay ya, data types are hard.